# How to optimize mysql query even it already used index

Tags: mysql

query is simple, as below:

```
select count(1) from ec_account a join ec_card b on a.id = b.AccountId
```

there are 2.5 million rows in either ec_account and ec_card.(InnoDB)

here is the execution plan:

[execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qubw.png)

as you see,
it already added index and used it, but the query still costed almost 60 seconds, is there any way could optimize it except changing database(mariadb has no such choke point as far as i know).

here is table DDL,ec_ccount:

```
CREATE TABLE `ec_account` (
  `Id` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `AccountType` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Status` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `IDCardType` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IDCardNo` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PasswordHalt` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sex` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BirthDay` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Mobile` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Linkman` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LinkmanRelation` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LinkmanTel` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Remark` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Nationality` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Nation` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MaritalStatus` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NativePlace` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Occupation` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BloodType` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Education` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LinkmanAddress` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HomeAddress` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CompanyName` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CompanyAddress` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CompanyTel` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Creator` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `LastModifier` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastModifyTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Avatar` longblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `IX_Name` (`Name`) USING HASH,
  KEY `Idx_IDCard_Account` (`IDCardType`,`IDCardNo`) USING HASH,
  KEY `Idx_Mobile` (`Mobile`) USING HASH,
  KEY `Idx_CreateTime` (`CreateTime`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and ec_card :

```
CREATE TABLE `ec_card` (
  `Id` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `AccountId` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `CardType` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `CardNo` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Status` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `IsPasswordAuth` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Idx_Unique_AccountId_CardType` (`AccountId`,`CardType`) USING HASH,
  UNIQUE KEY `Idx_Unique_CardType_CardNo` (`CardType`,`CardNo`) USING HASH,
  KEY `Idx_Uniques_AccountId` (`AccountId`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ec_card_ec_account_AccountId` FOREIGN KEY (`AccountId`) REFERENCES `ec_account` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: do you have index on `AccountId`?

Comment: What's the output of this query?

Comment: @walter the total count of rows, but it executed long time more than 50 seconds when first run

Comment: @Ali thanks, it executed less half time after added a index on `AccountId`,but i want to make it more faster,is there something else i could to do?

Comment: These are hard questions. I don't even know what time I was born.

Comment: The index on account id is redundant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a **workaround** for you. I think it would run much faster, and get the same result.

1. Calculate the total count of `ec_account`:

   `SELECT count(1) AS total_count FROM ec_account;`
2. Calculate the amount of records those existed in `ec_account` but not existed in `ec_card`:

   `SELECT count(1) AS missing_count`
   `FROM ec_account a LEFT JOIN ec_card b on a.id = b.AccountId`
   `WHERE b.AccountId IS NULL;`
3. Matched count = total_count - missing_count

The core problem here is that you combined two large table together, it requires a lot of memory and it apparently needs a lot of time to finish.

Comment: wow, it works and make result less than 10 seconds! that's a amazing way to reduce costs, thanks!

Comment: Yes, it reduced the records to be combined significantly. So it could run much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Not without fundamentally changing the query.

There are no conditions on your query! It selects all 2.5 million rows from `ec_card`, as well as every matching row from `ec_account`. Reading all this data from disk and sending it over the network is the bottleneck; there is no way to change that without changing what the query does.

Comment: Yes, there is no condition on query, but i think it should not execute so long time (it take about 30 seconds after i added index on `AccountId`,), i executed the same query in mariadb, it takes less than 10 seconds, so i wonder whether we can improve the performance more.

Answer (score 0):

try it using correlated subquery. This might help:

```
select count(1) from ec_account a where exists (select * from ec_card b 
where b.AccountId=a.id)
```

Also, other than indexing following strategies generally help:
- Denormalization
- Caching results
- Using a NoSQL database

Comment: Your query returns different results than the OP's query -- it doesn't return any of the columns from `ec_card`.